# Kafka Ktable-Ktable join on 3 Ktables with custom serializers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I wish to perform Ktable-Ktable join for 3 ktables, something similar like this

```
var joinedStream =
        person
            .join(
                address,
                Person::getAddress,
                valueJoiner,
                Materialized.with(Serdes.Integer(), jsonSerde))
            .leftJoin(addressType, this::getAddressType,valueJoiner);
```

While jsonSerde works when materializing the topic with customAvroServde the final join fails with serialization exception.

While doing this in stream join I was able to perform it with the StreamJoined.with functionality that helps in setting the serializers for the internal stream, but couldn't find anything such for ktables.

How should i perform the join with Ktables?

Comment: You can set `Serdes` in table-table joins via `Materialized` parameter

Comment: @pravin maurya did you get this to work? I've got a query with A B and C tables.  If I join A&B I get results, join A&C I get results. If I join A&B&C nothing happens past the first join